# CLASSIC ASP equivalent to jQuery.param in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I would like to know if there is any ASP resource that implement the same functionality of jQuery.param.  I am creating an JSON response on ASP, and for some characters (example: "/") I have received errors like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
v.extend.parseJSON jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2" while trying to "jQuery.parseJSON" the response. So, think I, I need to replace "/" by "%5C" and so on. There is anyway to "response.write" it without treating all characters that I need to replace manually?

I'll appreciate any help very much.

http://jsonlint.com/ :

```
 {
     "Name": "hmp",
     "URL": """    
 }
```

Parse error on line 3:

```
..."hmp",    "URL": """         }
----------------------^
```

Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'

Comment: Those characters really shouldn't be causing a problem. Have you tried passing the json to http://jsonlint.com to see exactly why it is failing
?

Comment: how to replace " on asp? it response.write anything.. than the bug occurs.

Comment: All of the `"` that arent the opening and closing of a value must be escaped, for example, `... ++ ++ \"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\""`

Comment: is there any function in asp that do it automatically? What do I need is to replace  \ by  \\ and " by  \"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write your own function to do this classic asp has no such function. to escape that " you have to use another " like so (classic asp with vbscript):

```
dim jsonStr

jsonStr = "{" &_
          "     ""Name"": ""hmp""," &_
          "     ""URL"": """" &_
          "}"

response.write jsonStr
```

you do not have to escape \ or / in classic asp with vbscript

[here is a class that implements some useful functionality when it comes to json generation](http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/04/26/generate-json-from-asp-datatypes/)